# Magento 2 - How to get cart items total in header.phtml

Tags: php, magento2

I am working with magento 2. I got php error when am using

```
echo Mage::helper(‘checkout/cart’)->getCart()->getItemsCount();
```

how to get cart item count in magento 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    $counter = $this->helper('\Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart'); 
    echo $counter->getItemsCount();
```

Comment: I have implemented your code but it is working only in cart page. the counter is not working on a home page or any other pages except cart page.

Comment: Did you get any error message? and please mention which Magento version you are using?

Comment: The class \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart should be injected in the constructor, rather than using $this->helper().

Answer (score 3):

Magento 2 provides 2 ways to show items count. One shows the number of individual items in the cart, while the other one shows the total count of items in the cart.

Let us say that cart helper is;

> $helper = $this->helper('\Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart');

When you do:

> echo $counter->getItemsCount();

it will show the number of individual items in the cart.

If you want to show total items count, then use:

> echo $counter->getSummaryCount();

Answer (score 1):

```
$objmanager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$session =  $objmanager->get("Magento\Checkout\Model\Session");
$quote =$session->getQuote();
$qty =  $quote->getItemsSummaryQty();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get total qty of the products in cart.

```
$helper = $this->helper('\Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart');
$helper->getItemsQty(); //get total qty of the cart
```

Answer (score -4):

Try this code

```
<?php
  $count = $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount();  //get total items in cart
  $total = $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal(); //get total price
  if($count==0)
  {
    echo $this->__('<a href="/checkout/cart" class="cartgo">(0 ITEMS)</a>',$count);
  }
  if($count==1)
  {
    echo $this->__('<a href="/checkout/cart" class="cartgo">(1 ITEM)</a>',$count);
  }
  if($count>1)
  {
    echo $this->__('<a href="/checkout/cart" class="cartgo">(%s ITMES)</a>',$count);
  }
  echo $this->__('', $this->helper('core')->formatPrice($total, false));
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but Sorry brother. I already tried this code.I got error only.i think it will work on magento 1.X. but am using magento 2. @Maavuz Saif

Comment: can you please paste error messages here which you are getting?

Comment: error is " [2016-05-11 05:53:10] main.CRITICAL: Class checkout/cart does not exist ".If i add this code to my header.phtml the whole section is missing from my homepage.